# Simple PowerShell parallel command execution

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing

I have two scripts I wish to run in parallel. I have a driver script I wish to use to execute the two parallel scripts.

The method I'm using of course does not run in parallel. I have looked all over the google universe, and at using a workflow, but I can't get that to work either.

Driver Script:

```
Clear-Host

$a = 4
$b = 29

$command1 = "C:\JUNK\Code\PowerScript\CS1.ps1 $a"
$command2 = "C:\JUNK\Code\PowerScript\CS2.ps1 $b"

#Invoke-Expression $command1
#Invoke-Expression $command2
```

The scripts to get called resemble this:

```
#CS1.ps1
Param(
    [string]$build
)

$ADATE = Get-Date
$DESTLOG1="C:\JUNK\Code\PowerScript\LOGS\status1.log"
$RunDefintion1 = ($build, $ADATE -join",")
Add-Content $DESTLOG1 $RunDefintion1
```

Comment: Relevant article: [parallel processing with powershell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/uktechnet/2016/06/20/parallel-processing-with-powershell/) that touches on both jobs and workflows.

Answer (score 0):

From powershell 2 upwards you could use the `Start-Job` command, something like this ( untested, might need some adjustments )

```
Start-Job { C:\JUNK\Code\PowerScript\CS1.ps1 $a }
Start-Job { C:\JUNK\Code\PowerScript\CS2.ps1 $b }
```

Comment: Davide 
I tried something like this yesterday and it didn't work. (Per a peers suggestion)
Not sure why it didn't. Here is what I had yesterday:

#Driver Script


$a = 4
$b = 29

$command1 = "C:\JUNK\Code\PowerScript\CS1.ps1 $a"
$command2 = "C:\JUNK\Code\PowerScript\CS2.ps1 $b"



$job1 = Start-Job {$command1}
$job2 = Start-Job {$command2}

 
# now wait till done
#$job1 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {$command1}

Wait-job -id $job1.Id
Wait-Job -id $job2.Id
Write-Host 'all done both jobs'


$COMPLETE = 'DONE'
$COMPLETE